# No syntax highlighting in tmux

Tags: syntax-highlighting, tmux

I installed `tmux` in iTerm 2.(Build 3.0.13) When I execute `vim` in `tmux`, syntax highlighting looks like this.

[image: no syntax highlighting]

But outside tmux, syntax highlighting looks fine.

[image: ordinary syntax highlighting]

My `$TERM` inside and outside tmux is `xterm-256color`. I also added

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

in `.tmux.conf` and added this

```
set t_Co=256
set t_AB=m
set t_AF=m
if &term =~ '256color'
    set t_ut=
endif
```

in `.vimrc`.

I also tried `tmux -2` command and read these questions.

[lose vim colorscheme in tmux mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode)

[Incorrect colors with vim in iTerm2 using Solarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278267/incorrect-colors-with-vim-in-iterm2-using-solarized)

Is this a problem of `tmux`, `vim`, or my configuration?

**EDIT:**

My `.vimrc` in GitHub Gist

https://gist.github.com/sohnryang/3c63397f332f2e30c7d7b2a83c3c9f52

Comment: What will happen when you start your tmux with `-2` option: `tmux -2`. Preferably when there are no sessions in tmux.

Comment: I used `tmux -2`, but the problem is same.

Comment: Could you share whole `.vimrc`?

Comment: Running on tmux in iTerm 3.0.12, setting `termguicolors` instantly changes my syntax highlighting to black and white (but still highlights, if only in bold).

Comment: @muru, I added `set termguicolors` in `.vimrc`, everything is same.

Comment: @sohnryang that's what I'm saying, maybe you shouldn't. You have it set right before you call pathogen.

Comment: What's the difference between setting termguicolors before calling pathogen and after calling pathogen?

Comment: @muru Anyway, I set `termguicolors` after pathogen, but problem persists.

Comment: @sohnryang what part of "maybe you shouldn't" do you not understand?

Comment: @muru I misunderstood your comment. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: [Try following these steps](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51). You have a whole lot of plugins so perhaps one of those is interfering.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem by myself.

as @Carpetsmoker♦ commented, I started to suspect that my `.vimrc` is a problem. I read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) and started vim with this command inside tmux.

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE -N ~/.vimrc
```

After starting vim with command above, I ran this command inside vim.

```
:syn on
:colorscheme solarized8_dark
```

These highlighted my `.vimrc` file. So, I started to debug my `.vimrc`.

Long story short, `set termguicolors` was the problem. If I ran vim with `set termguicolors` commented in `.vimrc`, I could see corrected syntax highlighting in tmux.

Comment: I had the same issue. would be great to get `termguicolors` working on tmux though

Comment: thank you! this fixed it, I spent quite a while trying to figure this out

Answer (score 9):

From the vim manual: `:h termguicolors` recommends reading `:h xterm-true-color`, also see `:h $TERM`

```
Sometimes setting 'termguicolors' is not enough and one has to set the |t_8f|
and |t_8b| options explicitly.  [ ... these are]  only set [to some default] when `$TERM` is `xterm`.
```

I use a condition similar to the below: (nvim recommends *not* using `&term` but rather `$TERM` )

```
if $TERM =~# '256color' && ( $TERM =~# '^screen'  || $TERM =~# '^tmux' )
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    set termguicolors
endif
```

Comment: This one worked for me on NVim. Running on Arch and Fish shell

Answer (score 5):

I actually made it work just fine with `termguicolors`. This is what I did
1. in my ~/.bash_profile i put this:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

and inside my ~/.vimrc I had this

```
syntax enable
colorscheme Spacegray

set termguicolors
```

and it worked perfectly! [reference](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6096#issuecomment-279224144)

Comment: :syn on
: colorscheme Spacegray
: set termguicolors

Comment: In my case, it worked well without `set termguicolors`. Thank you, anyway!

Comment: Adding the `export` fixed it in my case, nice work!