# No syntax highlighting in git commit with nvim

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, terminal, microsoft-windows, git

I have installed nvim using scoop on two Windows 11 systems. The installation works fine on my laptop (Surface Laptop 3). On my desktop, when I run `git commit` with nvim set as my editor, the terminal (Powershell or cmd) is in black and white (see images below). The problem persists with or without my lua config (which is just bare bones `set`ting variables, no plugins).

The only difference between the two machines that I've noticed is that if nvim is run in a terminal normally with `nvim`,`:echo $TERM` outputs `vtpcon` on both machines. However, when nvim is opened with `git commit`, `:echo $TERM` outputs `xterm-256color` on my laptop, and `cygwin` on my desktop.

Curiously, setting my git editor to `vim` (rather than `nvim`) on my desktop and running `git commit` opens vim with the correct colours, and `:echo $TERM` outputs `cygwin` in this window.

I'm very new to (n)vim so I'm not sure how to fix this or what is even wrong. Help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry. `:echo $TERM` outputs something different on my machines depending on whether I've run nvim normally in the terminal with `nvim`, or if it's opened via `git commit`. On both machines, opening it normally with `nvim` yields `$TERM` as `vtpcon`, but when nvim is opened via `git commit` (after setting it as git's `core.editor`) on my laptop `$TERM` says xterm-256color`, and on my desktop it says `cygwin`. I will reword it in the question now.

Comment: One way to definitively rule out config problems is [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) (not mentioned there is also `vim --clean`). After that, it _could_ be terminfo-related, but I kind of doubt it since you said Vim with `$TERM=cygwin` worked.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Unfortunately nothing suggested in that post worked. I set my `core.editor` to `"nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N"` and similar, but `git commit` still has no syntax highlighting. Debugging only shows the line `cmd: augroup nvim_terminal`. I have no plugins, but turning them off with the flag did nothing. I generated full log files for both nvim and vim (i.e. just `(n)vim -V9logfile.log`) and the diff turned up no lines. As an aside, I tried installing neovim via winget and that didn't fix anything either.

Comment: Sorry, note that after `nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N` you might need to do `:filetype on`, `:syntax enable`, `:edit` (I can't recall which if any of those are NeoVim defaults). But the point is that this _likely_ means your config is not the culprit. Could be a bug /shrug

Comment: Still nothing! It's not the end of the world I guess; at least `vim` works with syntax highlighting. I've wasted enough time researching this problem so I think it's time I move on. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with git! I noticed that if I opened the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file with nvim directly, i.e., `nvim .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, syntax highlighting worked. This made me think that the problem was actually with git, so after resetting my config did nothing, I just reinstalled it and now syntax highlighting is working for commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue today with `git commit -v` (only within TMUX). After reading this issue [No syntax highlighting in tmux](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10708/no-syntax-highlighting-in-tmux), I commented out `set termguicolors` in my .vimrc and it fixed it.